# scroll to next div already in browser

Tags: javascript, scrollto

I have a series of divs that are 100% height with a scroll to function that takes you to the next div out of the viewport on background click. However, if the next div is already slightly in the viewport the whole thing is counted as being visible and the scroll to bypasses it. Can anyone offer direction on how to get the script to scroll to the div even if it's partially in the viewport already?

[Codepen here.](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KwrkH)

If you begin scrolling slightly in the codepen and then click on the background you'll see that it doesnt scroll you to the div that's already in the viewport but the div after that.

```
$(document).ready(function() {


// get initial nav height
        var $window = $(window);
        var wst = $window.scrollTop();
        var th = $('div.top').height();
        var currentSlide = $('#wrapper').data( 'current-slide', $('div.slide').eq(0) );

        $('div.scroll_images').css({ height: 'auto', overflow: 'visible', top: 0 });
        $('div.scroll_images div.inner').css({ position: 'absolute', top: 0 });
        $('div.slide').each(function() {
                $(this).css('padding',function() {
                return (($(window).height()-$(this).height())/2)+'px 0'
            });
        });



            // scrollto for click on slide
            jQuery.fn.scrollTo = function(hash) {
                $this = $(this);
                st = $this.offset().top - th; // subtract nav height
                $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: st }, 550
                );
            }

                $('#wrapper').click(function(e){
                //get the current slide index from the body tag.
                $this = currentSlide.data( 'current-slide' );
                $next = $(".slide:below-the-fold");

                if($next.length) {
                $next.scrollTo($next.attr('id'));
                //Save the next slide as the current.
                $('#wrapper').data( 'current-slide', $next );
                } else {
                //Throw us back to the top.
                $('div.slide:first').scrollTo($('div.slide:first').attr('id'));
                //Save the first slide as the first slide, which 
                //Cycles us back to the top.
                $('#wrapper').data( 'current-slide', $('div.slide:first'));
                }
            })
                //Images fade in
                $('img').hide();
                $('img').each(function(i) {
                if (this.complete) {
                $(this).fadeIn();
                } else {
                $(this).load(function() {
                $(this).fadeIn();
                });
                }
            });

                //Stop links affecting scroll function
                $("a").click(function(e) {
                e.stopPropagation(); 
                });

});




(function($) {

    $.belowthefold = function(element, settings) {
        var fold = $(window).height() + $(window).scrollTop();
        return fold <= $(element).offset().top - settings.threshold;
    };


    $.extend($.expr[':'], {
        "below-the-fold": function(a, i, m) {
            return $.belowthefold(a, {threshold : 0});
        }
    });

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Simply make it scroll to the next closest <div>?

Comment: So if you've scrolled to a position between two divs, the background click takes you to the second of the two divs to make it centered in the browser window, as opposed to the next one outside the viewport which it's scrolling to at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I might try to do: go through each div in the series. Find the div who's `offset()` is closest to `$(window).scrollTop()`. Now, find the `next()` div after the "current" one and scroll to it.

For comparing the `offset()` of each div, try something like this:

```
var closest = $('[selector]:first');
$('[selector]').each(function() {
    var oldDistance = Math.abs(closest.offset() - $(window).scrollTop());
    var newDistance = Math.abs($(this).offset() - $(window).scrollTop());

    if(newDistance < oldDistance) {
        closest = $(this);
    }
}
```